# DSE Search - SOLR HTTP connection - fail-over,loadbalancing

Tags: spring, solr, datastax-enterprise, solrcloud, datastax-startup

We want to use DSE Search from  Datastax in our application.
We have Cassandra on all nodes and SOLR on half of the nodes.

We can connect to one SOLR instance

```
  @Bean
  public SolrServer solrServer() {
    String solrHost = environment.getRequiredProperty(SOLR_HOST);
    return new HttpSolrServer(solrHost);
  }
```

We would like to connect to SOLR in order to have load balancing and failover similar to the connection to SOLR Cloud :

```
  @Bean
  public SolrServer solrServer() throws MalformedURLException {
    return new CloudSolrServer(environment.getRequiredProperty(ZK_HOST), 
            new LBHttpSolrServer(
                    environment.getRequiredProperty(SOLR_HOST1), 
                    environment.getRequiredProperty(SOLR_HOST2),
                    environment.getRequiredProperty(SOLR_HOST3)));
  }
```

Is something like this possible with DSE Search?

Comment: What snitch. Workloads must be the same by logical datacenter

Comment: Datacenter 1 - Spark + Cassandra (3 nodes), 
Datacenter 2 - SOLR(DSE Search) + Cassandra (3 nodes).

Keyspace:ALTER KEYSPACE example
WITH replication = {
    'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'Datacenter 1' : 3,
    'Datacenter 2' : 3
};

Comment: Automatic failover and load balancing is already done by the DataStax drivers.